# Positioning of a pop up

Tags: jquery, html, popup, window, position

All divs change position horizontally if you make the browser window larger. Is there way to prevent this happening? Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using jQuery on the page, why don't you try the jQuery UI position utility:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/

This allows you to position any element relative to another element.

Comment: You have to include the jQuery UI script just after you include jQuery: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Here's the implementation with your code in a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swatkins/bpHS3/  -- Also, you're not using the HTML5 DTD, so you'll need to add `type="text/javascript"` and `type="text/css"` to your js and style tags.

Comment: you can also create a more lean download from this page: http://jqueryui.com/download

Answer (score 1):

```
setPositionPopUp: function ($posObj, $dlg, topOff, leftOff) {
            var dl = $dlg.get(0);
            if ($dlg.length == 0) {
                return;
            }

            if (topOff == null)
                topOff = 20;
            if (leftOff == null)
                leftOff = 20;

            var v = $posObj.offset();
            dl.style.position = "absolute";
            dl.style.top = (v.top + topOff) + 'px';
            dl.style.left = (v.left + leftOff) + 'px';
            dl.style.zIndex = "10000";
            $dlg.fadeIn("slow");
        }
```

I have used the above code to achieve what you want. If you dont want to include the whole jquery ui file.

You can call it like follows:

```
setPositionPopup($('.colors_box'), $('img'));
```

Choose your selectors correctly obviously.